# Silverlight HttpWebRequest BinaryReader second Read operation always takes a long time (12 seconds)

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpwebrequest, binaryreader, mediastreamsource

I am creating a Silverlight application that utilizes an H.264 MediaStreamSource implementation in order to stream live video from a server. I have a Multipart streamer that I wrote that reads the samples frame by frame.

When I connect to a server running on my local machine, it takes 12 seconds to read the second byte from the response stream in the ReadHeaders() function. So basically it connects to the host instantly, reads one byte successfully, the subsequent ReadByte() blocks (if you look at where the call stack is it is in another thread at:   System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.ReadOperation(object state)). Every time I test this it consistently takes the 12 seconds. Once this time has passed, all subsequent reads are immediate and the application runs great. If I use this same code in just a simple .NET console application, there is no 12 second delay.

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
        byte[] imgBuf = new byte[ChunkSize * ChunkSize];
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState;
        int contentLength = 0;
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(res);
            // notify delegate of main headers

            // get the response stream and start reading
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            Dictionary<string, string> headers;
            while (m_Running)
            {
                // read multipart response headers and notify delegate
                headers = ReadHeaders(reader);

                // check if end of stream
                if (headers.ContainsKey(CustomHeaders.EndOfStreamHeader) 
                    && headers[CustomHeaders.EndOfStreamHeader] != null
                    && String.Compare(headers[CustomHeaders.EndOfStreamHeader], "yes") == 0)
                {
                    // notify delegate if end of stream has been reached
                }
                // determine length of data to read
                string cl = headers["Content-Length"];
                if (cl != null)
                {
                    contentLength = Int32.Parse(cl);
                }
                byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(contentLength);

                if (data.Length > 0)
                {
                    // notify delegate of multipart data
                }
                // Yield to other threads waiting to be executed
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            reader.Close();
            resp.Close();
            req.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // notify delegate of any errors that occurred
        }
```

The ReadHeaders() function:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> ReadHeaders(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
        while (m_Running)
        {
            buffer.Add(reader.ReadByte());
            if (buffer.EndsWith(EndOfHeaderBytes))
            {
                break;
            }
            // Yield to other threads waiting to be executed
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        return buffer.ToHeadersDictionary();
    }
```

Edit: Here is the call stack of the two threads.

Worker Thread   Worker Thread   GenIIIWebClient.CVRESTLib.HttpMultipartStreamer.ReadHeaders Normal
                        [In a sleep, wait, or join]
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext) + 0x21 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(long timeout, bool exitContext) + 0x21 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) + 0x1f bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne() + 0x10 bytes
                        System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x40 bytes
                        System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) + 0x38 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Stream.ReadByte() + 0x28 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte() + 0x1d bytes
                        GenIIIWebClient!GenIIIWebClient.CVRESTLib.HttpMultipartStreamer.ReadHeaders(System.IO.BinaryReader reader) Line 201 + 0x19 bytes
                        GenIIIWebClient!GenIIIWebClient.CVRESTLib.HttpMultipartStreamer.OnGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult res) Line 126 + 0xf bytes
                        System.Windows.dll!System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InvokeGetResponseCallback.AnonymousMethod__18(object state2) + 0x11 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x3e bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x97 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x5a bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x1b3 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x5 bytes
                        [Native to Managed Transition]
                        [Appdomain Transition]
                        [Native to Managed Transition]

Unflagged       5096    5   Worker Thread   Worker Thread   [In a sleep, wait, or join] Normal
                        [In a sleep, wait, or join]
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext) + 0x21 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(long timeout, bool exitContext) + 0x21 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) + 0x1f bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne() + 0x10 bytes
                        System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.ReadOperation(object state) + 0x8a bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x3e bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x97 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x5a bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x1b3 bytes
                        mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x5 bytes
                        [Native to Managed Transition]
                        [Appdomain Transition]
                        [Native to Managed Transition]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see the real cause from here but it can be something related to thread management.
The first suspect I see here is `m_Running`. Focus on that. Maybe some threading stuffs vary for the types of projects.

Have you tried using a waitHandle instead of giving a Sleep(1),

```
ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

while(true)
{
  waitHandle.Wait();
  waitHandle.Reset();

  while(ThereIsAJobToExecute)
 {
    // Process the jobs
    // You should waitHandle.Set() in a callback or when you read it
 }
}
```

My second offer for the line below is giving an initial list size

> *List  < byte > buffer = new List < byte >();*

Initial size for the type List<> DOES NOT mean a limit such an Array size. If you do not give a predefined size List resizes itself. So giving an expected number is a plus.

```
List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>(1024...etc);
```

Comment: I just gave the list initialization a shot, it did not seem to improve things much. I edited my original question by adding the call stacks of the 2 threads. They are both stuck in WaitOne() calls, but I do not know who the InternalNetworkStream is waiting on?

Comment: I didn't expect a big impact for list Init. Just offered. I can't see your edit ( because I haven't got a computer now ,I'm using a phone). I can anticipate that WaitOne called from Sleep operation . Do not use WaitOne or Sleep , try my first suggestion.Sleeping 1ms isn't a true way for other threads. You should use reset and set.  Especially if you are looping in a while.